# get Asp calender selected Date into JQuery function

Tags: jquery

I have Asp.net Calendar . I want to Get Selected Date from Date Cell and Save it in DB with some Text .. For Text I Used Prompt Dialog..

[image]

Calendar1_SelectionChanged event is not firing  . So I cannot get selected Date ..

this is My prompt Function

```
function openPrompt() {
    var nName = prompt("Enter Title");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Events.aspx/SaveUser",
        data: '{user: ' + JSON.stringify(nName) + '}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert("User has been added successfully.");
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });

}
```

and web method ..

```
  public static void SaveUser(object user)
    {
        Events e = new Events();

        e._Event= user.ToString();
    }
```

Can I get Selected Cell Date in JQuery ?Or By Any other method ??

Edit : I also Tried this :

```
var calendarDate = '<%= Calendar1.SelectedDate %>';

            var x = document.getElementById('<%= Calendar1.ClientID%>').value;
```

Not working ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved --Use JQuery Full Calender

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var events_array = [
        {
        title: 'Test1',
        start: new Date(2012, 8, 20),
        tip: 'Personal tip 1'},
    {
        title: 'Test2',
        start: new Date(2012, 8, 21),
        tip: 'Personal tip 2'}
    ];

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        selectable: true,
        events: events_array,
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            element.attr('title', event.tip);
        },

           select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
         // start contains the date you have selected
         // end contains the end date. 
         // Caution: the end date is exclusive (new since v2).
         var allDay = !start.hasTime && !end.hasTime;
         alert(["Event Start date: " + moment(start).format(),
                "Event End date: " + moment(end).format(),
                "AllDay: " + allDay].join("\n"));
    }


    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5o66w860/

thanks Steve for helping

post

[Full Calender not showing selected Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643517/full-calender-not-showing-selected-date/32643682#32643682)

Answer (score 0):

AJAX runs on the client side, while `Calendar1_SelectionChanged` runs on the server side, so they are two different worlds.

You can get the selected date in your `SaveUser` function. Something like this:

```
public void SaveUser(object user)
{
    DateTime MyDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
    ...
    ...
}
```

**EDIT** To answer your question about AJAX not hitting the `SaveUser` function after deleting the `static` keyword.

You only provided the code for the `SaveUser` function in your question, so I have no idea about the rest of the code in that class. I assume that you marked the `SaveUser` function with a `[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]` attribute. This method looks at the requested URL `Events.aspx/SaveUser`, parse the end `SaveUser` string after the page name, and automatically calls the `SaveUser` function. In this method, the function needs to be static.

That's nice because it works automatically, so you don't have to code anything. But you don't really have to use this method. You can use a standard HTML/ASP approach and handle the request by yourself. This way you will have full control. Instead of `Events.aspx/SaveUser`, use a standard query variable, something like `Events.aspx?SaveUser=1` or `Events.aspx?Action=SaveUser` or whatever you like. Your AJAX will look like this:

```
function openPrompt() {
    var nName = prompt("Enter Title");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Events.aspx?Action=SaveUser",
        data: '{user: ' + JSON.stringify(nName) + '}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert("User has been added successfully.");
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

Now handle the query string in the `Events.aspx` page, check for the `Action` variable and call the `SaveUser` function accordingly:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    If(Request.QueryString["Action"] == "SaveUser")
       SaveUser();
}
```

And finally here is how your `SaveUser` function will look like:

```
public void SaveUser()
{
    User user = null;
    If(Request.Form["user"] != null)
        user = System.Web.Script.Serialization.serializer.Deserialize<User>(Request.Form["user"]);
    DateTime MyDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Notice that you have to deserialize your JSON data manually now (it was done automatically for you with the `[WebMethod]`). For that, you need to import the `System.Web.Script.Serialization` library.

Comment: SaveUser is a static method . Calendar1 will be null . You cant bind page control like this here

Comment: Yes, why not? In fact AJAX cannot call any function. It can only call a webpage (or web service) and retrieve the results, that's all. It is your page that decides how to respond to the AJAX call. So when your AJAX calls `Events.aspx/SaveUser`, the `Events.aspx` page receives the call and decides what to do with it. In this case it finds the `SaveUser` value passed at the end of the URL and decides to call the `SaveUser` function. In this context, it is your code behind the `Events.aspx` page that will decides whether it can call static function or not.

Comment: I think using webservice is a long approach . How can i approach calender in web service page ?

Comment: I said "webpage or web service", so both are fine. You don't need to change what you're using now. Simply delete the `static` keyword in front or your `SaveUser` function and it will work. I don't see your entire class to judge 100%, but give it a try.

Comment: yes . by that  . $.ajax not hitting method . can you provide jsfiddle ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89985/discussion-between-neeraj-verma-and-racil-hilan).